# android sqlite orderby datetime always fetches 1st row

Tags: android, sqlite

I am storing date and time in column of type DATETIME. After that I am trying to retrieve the earliest time.
I am using this query

```
String query_to_fetch_earliest="select *  from "+TABLE_NAME+" order  by datetime("+KEY_DATETIME+") DESC LIMIT 1";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query_to_fetch_earliest, null);
```

But i always endup getting 1st row.
Please help.

Comment: maybe becouse you put LIMIT 1

Comment: Also if you're interested in the earliest first, change `DESC` to `ASC`

Comment: @laalto both did not help

Comment: @LuS  I need the earliest one.. that means one row..

Comment: Consider adding some details to the question, such as what your data actually looks like

Comment: @LuS  and laalto  you both are right.. i removed LIMIT 1 and changed DESC to ASC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set limit, just do as below

```
  String query_to_fetch_earliest="select *  from "+TABLE_NAME+" order  by         datetime("+KEY_DATETIME+") DESC ";
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query_to_fetch_earliest, null);
```

Comment: here I will get all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +
  TABLE_NAME +
  " WHERE " + 
  KEY_DATETIME +
  " IN (SELECT max(" +
  KEY_DATETIME +
  ") FROM " +
  TABLE_NAME +
  ")"
```