# Fetching SQLite Data Using Order By DateTime But Not Work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to Get All data (Date and time wise) but it's not helpful for me AND also Don't Show any error

Follow this Below links But It's Not Helpful For Me :

- [android sqlite orderby datetime always fetches 1st row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508415/android-sqlite-orderby-datetime-always-fetches-1st-row?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Order By datetime column SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268270/order-by-datetime-column-sqlite)
- [Why is the ORDER BY not working in a Sqlite query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129782/why-is-the-order-by-not-working-in-a-sqlite-query)

**Insert Record in to `SQLite` database :**

```
private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public long insertCompany(Company company){
    //String sql = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_COMPANY_NAME, company.getName());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_COMPANY_WEBSITE,company.getWebsite());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_COMPANY_EMAIL,company.getEmail());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_HOME,company.getPhoneHome());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_PRIMARY,company.getPhonePrimary());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_COMPANY_ADDRESS,company.getAddressLine1());
    long company_id = db.insert(COMPANY, null, values);

    return company_id;
}
```

**Below Code is i'll implement in my Database but It's can't work :**

```
List<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<Company>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + COMPANY + " ORDER BY (" + KEY_CREATED_AT + ") ";

Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);

SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

**Full Code :**

```
public List<Company> getAllCompany(){

    List<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<Company>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + COMPANY + " ORDER BY (" + KEY_CREATED_AT + ") ";

    Log.e(TAG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Company com = new Company();
            com.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            com.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_NAME)));
            com.setWebsite(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_WEBSITE)));
            com.setEmail(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_EMAIL)));
            com.setPhoneHome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_HOME)));
            com.setPhonePrimary(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_PRIMARY)));
            com.setAddressLine1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_ADDRESS)));
            com.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
            //com.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_UPDATED_AT)));
            companyList.add(com);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return companyList;
}
```

**See Below Image For Batter understanding Data was not show in Date and Time wise :**

[image]

Help me :)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you want latest first ?

Comment: Yes @NiranjPatel

Comment: order by `field` desc

Comment: what is datatype of **KEY_CREATED_AT** column?

Comment: VARCHAR @NiranjPatel

Comment: that it won't work, use miliseconds instead of date string or use datetime datatype.

Comment: Sry i can't understand what u mean? @NiranjPatel

Comment: make KEY_CREATED_AT as INTEGER and store date like yyyyMMddhhmmss. So for this instance the KEY_CREATED_AT  will be 20180404130001. Now use "order by KEY_CREATED_AT desc" at the end of the query

Comment: are you store 04-04-2018 10:58 AM in database?

Comment: yes this format i need bro Now i want only Order Bye date and time @NiranjPatel

Comment: Sry bro but i need this format for my output @Mayur_Thakur

Comment: you have to change your format for store value in DB, either store milliseconds of date or yyyymmddhhMMss.

Comment: So to show the date you can convert that format into the format you want

Comment: Can paste code about Insert Date @NiranjPatel

Comment: post your insert code then I can modify it.

Comment: See bro I'll update my Question @NiranjPatel

Comment: @MohammadAli please check my answer

Comment: Ya bro i'll just check it @NiranjPatel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VARCHAR not working for date while sorting data. You can insert milliseconds in database and format date while show in View.

replace this line in `insertCompany` Method.

```
values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

replace this line while getting data from DB.

```
long time = Long.parseLong(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
com.setDate(getFromatDate(time));
```

Method for format data from Milliseconds.

```
public String getFromatDate(long dateTime) {
    String formatedDate;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);
    Date mDate = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a", new Locale("en"));
    formatedDate = sdf.format(mDate);
    return formatedDate;
}
```

also u can add **`DESC`** at end of your Query See below code:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + COMPANY + " ORDER BY (" + KEY_CREATED_AT + ") DESC " ;
```

Comment: Can i change a Query of select Data ?

Comment: no need, if not working then you can just add **DESC** at end of line

Comment: Thank You So much my Brother it's work like Charm @Niraj Patel

Comment: Bro can u give me 1 more Suggestion **If I Update any data then it's retrieve data DateTime wise** **??** @NirajPatel

Comment: you can also udpate **KEY_CREATED_AT** value while updating data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168196/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-niranj-patel).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is full implementation example.**

If KEY_CREATED_AT is a char or varchar and not a date otherwise you can simply use order by clause that would be fine.

You can use CONVERT to change the values to a date and sort by that

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     COMPANY
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, KEY_CREATED_AT ,101)  DESC
```

The problem with that is, as Sparky points out in the comments, if KEY_CREATED_AT has a value that can't be converted to a date the query won't execute.

This means you should either exclude the bad rows or let the bad rows go to the bottom of the results

To exclude the bad rows just add WHERE IsDate(KEY_CREATED_AT ) = 1

To let let the bad dates go to the bottom you need to use CASE

e.g.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
       WHEN IsDate(KEY_CREATED_AT) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DateTime,KEY_CREATED_AT,101)
       ELSE null
    END DESC
```

Comment: i'll want to getting all data not any one  single data or Selected data

Comment: use time stamp for date filter this is the best way

Comment: you can use order by CONVERT(datetime, EventDate ) desc for all fileds

Comment: What is EventDate ? @krishankTripathi

Comment: just pass your varaible i.e KEY_CREATED_DATE that have the value of date in string or varchar in place of Eventdate.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the 'order' to your query in order by clause

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + COMPANY + " ORDER BY (" + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DESC)";
```

You can use either ASC or DESC as per required behavior.

Comment: i'll try also this one but not useful for me

Comment: well thanks for the advice, however no comments were made while i started writing the answer